# Define dynamic class methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know this question has been asked several times, but I think never in this conditions.

I try to create an "helper" for my models (an `acts_as`), for automatically set a status from a status_id.

```
acts_as_statusable :status, [ :in_progress, closed ]
```

This helper creates methods `status`, `status=(sym)`, `in_progress?`, `closed?` and named scopes `in_progress` and `closed`.

My helper work, this is its code put in `lib/`

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.acts_as_statusable(*args)
    field_name = args.first
    field_name_id = :"#{field_name}_id"
    statuses = args.second

    # Define getter
    define_method(field_name) do
      return nil if self.send(field_name_id).nil?
      return statuses[self.send(field_name_id)]
    end

    # Define setter
    define_method(:"#{field_name}=") do |v|
      return self.send(:"#{field_name_id}=", statuses.index(v))
    end

    # Define a status? for each status,
    # and a named scope .status
    statuses.each do |status|
      define_method(:"#{status}?") do
        return self.send(field_name) == status
      end
      scope status, -> { where(["#{table_name}.#{field_name_id} = ?", statuses.index(status)]) }
    end

    validates field_name_id, :inclusion => { :in => (0...statuses.length).to_a }
  end
end
```

**Now, the problem**

I need to have a Class method, for every class using `acts_as_statusable`, named `status_index(sym)` which returns the status_id from a status.

The problem is that every solutions I found for defining a class models are using `Module`, `extend` or `intend`, but I can not insert the `statuses` variable of the `acts_as_statusable` line into this modules...

How can I do this ? I use Rails 4.

Comment: Did you try define_singleton_method?

Comment: I don't get what you want `status_index(sym)` to do. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Why not simply use a state machine ? Maybe I misunderstood the question, but it looks for me like reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `class_eval`, and `class_variable_set`

```
class_variable_set :"@@#{field_name}_options", statuses

class_eval <<-RUBY
  def self.status_index(sym)
    @@#{field_name}_options.index(sym)
  end
RUBY
```

which in your case will give a

`@@status_options` class variable
and a
`status_index(sym)`
method that returns the offset of the given status

Comment: @xlembouras Thanks ! Works perfectly. I haven't think about that.

Answer (score 2):

**xlembouras** - your solution works great! I have two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_statusable :status, [ :little, :big ]
end 

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_statusable :status, [ :in_progress, :closed ]
end
```

'rails c' execution:

```
> User.status_index(:little)
=> 0 
User.status_index(:big)
=> 1 
> Price.status_index(:closed)
=> 1 
> Price.status_index(:in_progress)
=> 0
```

I modified the structure, and used code written by **ForgetTheNorm**.
Rails 4, ActiveSupport::Concern used

**lib/active_record_extension.rb :**

```
module ActiveRecordExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern  
end
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)
```

**config/initializers/extensions.rb :**

```
require "active_record_extension"
```

**config/initializers/active_record_monkey_patch.rb**

```
class ActiveRecord::Base     
  def self.acts_as_statusable(*args)
    ...
    # ForgetTheNorm's CODE..
    ...
    # xlembouras CODE:
    class_variable_set :"@@#{field_name}_options", statuses

    class_eval <<-RUBY
      def self.status_index(sym)
        @@#{field_name}_options.index(sym)
      end
    RUBY
  end
end
```

Comment: nice proof of concept